# Examples of compressed Gorenstein ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a Gorenstein local Artinian ring of socle degree $s$ and embedding dimension $e>1$. We set

$$
\varepsilon_i=\min\left\{ \binom{e-1+s-i}{e-1}, \binom{e-1+i}{e-1}\right\} \quad\text{for all $i$ with $0\le i\le s$.}
$$
Then
$
\lambda(R)\le \sum_{i=0}^e \varepsilon_i.
$

**We say that $R$ is a *compressed Gorenstein ring* of socle degree $s$ and embedding dimension $e$ if $R$ has maximal length, that is, $\lambda(R)=\sum_{i=0}^e \varepsilon_i$.**

My question is:

**How to generate some examples of *compressed Gorenstein ring*.**

Comment: What is $\lambda(R)$?

Comment: @Sasha $\lambda(R)$ = length of $R$.

Comment: I guess $k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]/(x_1^2,x_2^2,\dots,x_n^2)$ is a series of such examples.

Comment: @Sasha, Thanks for yout help. This is a Complete Intersection ring, can we get examples of compressed Gorenstein ring which is not complete intersection.

Comment: What about $k[x,y,z]/(xy,xz,yz,x^3-y^3,y^3-z^3)$?